# Can't resolve parameters for Service. This will become an error in Angular 6.x

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm having a warning when I ng build my Logging library that has a base abstract class. Upon checking similar problems here, most of them are just saying that I should remove the @Injectable in the base class which I already did. By the way my class dependencies are all using Inject since they are all `InjectionTokens` that are created in `LoggingModule.forRoot()`.

**logging.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [],
  exports: []
})
export class LoggingModule {

  public static forRoot(
    appName: string,
    customLogger: Provider,
    customLoggerDeps: Provider[] = [],
    filteredLogLevels: Array<LogLevel | string> = [],
    filterStrategies: Array<
      (logLevel: LogLevel | string, filter: LogLevel | string) => boolean
      > = []
  ): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LoggingModule,
      providers: [ // provide injection tokens here based from parameters 
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**logger.ts**

```
export abstract class Logger {
    // abstract method declarations here
}
```

**CustomLogger.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomLogger extends Logger {
  constructor(
    @Inject(APP_NAME_TOKEN) protected appName: string,
    @Optional()
    @Inject(FILTER_STRATEGIES)
    protected filterStrategies: Array<
      (logLevel: LogLevel | string, filter: LogLevel | string) => boolean
    >,
    @Optional()
    @Inject(FILTERED_LOG_LEVELS)
    protected filteredLogLevels: Array<LogLevel | string>
  ) {
    super(appName, filterStrategies, filteredLogLevels);
  }
}
```

I'm a bit confused why angular don't know how to inject those tokens. Any help would be appreciated.

By the way I'm using `Angular 6.1` with CLI

Comment: do you implement all abstract functions and fields in your ConsoleLoggerService? i got this type of error when accidentally using @Injectable on an abstract class.

Comment: Yes I've implemented all of them, also as I've mentioned, there's no Injectable decorator used in the base class

Comment: can you provide a simple reproducable example?

Comment: I was able to make it work by importing my `InjectionToken` directly instead of the barrel.